# Where to find datasets for creating CARTO VL maps?

Tags: data, carto, origin-destination, carto-vl

Is there any way to download example datasets like NYC taxi and origin-destination data? Like those that show flight paths from and to some cities. I think it'd help me greatly if I could somehow get those data and try to create CARTO VL animations on my own.

Comment: For open data I think that the best place to ask a question like this is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in the demos is probably specifically processed, but it is not difficult find these open datasets from 'the Internet'. For example, they are in Google [BigQuery open datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/nyc-tlc-trips), and e.g. https://github.com/toddwschneider/nyc-taxi-data has many useful links.

Comment: please @Sonic mark the question as answered please :___)